# Can reuse makefile multiple times within single execution?

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have:

```
# ./Makefile 
CLUSTER=dev
include Makefile.cluster.mk

CLUSTER=local
include Makefile.cluster.mk
```

And in:

```
# ./Makefile.cluster.mk
${CLUSTER}.cmd:
    cmd ${CLUSTER}
```

So now I can call:

```
make dev.cmd
make local.cmd
```

Great! Except the variable is evaluated too late. Running:

```
$ make local.cmd    # cmd local
$ make dev.cmd      # Also cmd local !
```

Make sense: according to: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html
rule steps are deferred evaluation (vs. immediate/on file load).

```
immediate : immediate ; deferred
        deferred
```

Is there a better/other way to compose a set of make commands without maintaining multiple copies of the same file?

Comment: Is [CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/index.html) related to your problem? Otherwise, why do you use `cmake` tag?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do it, even beyond the options above; you could use static pattern rules:

```
CLUSTERS := dev local

$(CLUSTERS:%=%.cmd) : %.cmd :
        cmd $*
```

If you really want to have stuff in a separate makefile you can use target-specific variables; change your `Makefile.cluster.mk` to do this:

```
# ./Makefile.cluster.mk
${CLUSTER}.cmd: CLUSTER := $(CLUSTER)
${CLUSTER}.cmd:
        cmd ${CLUSTER}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better/other way to compose a set of make commands without maintaining multiple copies of the same file?

Often it's pattern rules.  In the case of your particular example, you might do

**Makefile**

```
%.cmd:
        cmd '$*'
```

However, that particular version will enable *any* `make foo.cmd`, which might not be what you want.

---

Sometimes it's to make better use of the tools available to you.  For example,

**Makefile.cluster.mk**

```
${CLUSTER}.cmd:
        arg='$@'; cmd "$${arg%.cmd}"
```

That extracts the wanted cluster name from the name of the target.

---

Occasionally it is [`$(eval)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html#index-evaluating-makefile-syntax).

(See the manual for an example.)

---

And from time to time, it's "don't do that."  For example,

**Makefile**

```
CLUSTERS = dev local
CMDS = $(patsubst %,%.cmd,$(CLUSTERS))

$(CMDS):
        arg='$@'; cmd "$${arg%.cmd}"
```

That defines only `dev.cmd` and `local.cmd` targets, and avoids duplicating the recipe.

Comment: Thanks.
Hmmm... For the sanity of my teammates, will implement this in Python.